# Relativity asymmetry?

Tags: special-relativity, time, observers, inertial-frames

If you have two bodies that move towards each other at a constant velocity, each body will observe the other body experience time faster. This does not make sense to me because if you had a person with a clock on each body and the two bodies met and they compared each others time, person one would see person 2's clock running faster and person 2 would observe person 1's clock running faster. Where is the flaw in my thinking?

Comment: Everything is relative to an **observer**, even notions like "faster", "slower" and "simultaneous".

Answer (score 3):

To measure time, a duration, you need *two* moments – when you press "start" and "stop" button on the stopwatch, respectively. But because the two objects are moving relatively to each other, it isn't possible for them to "meet" at both moments. If their locations coincide at the "start" moment, for example, so that their clocks may be compared at this "start" moment, these two positions will inevitably fail to coincide at the "stop" moment, so the final moments can't be compared.

To compare the durations, you need to change the velocity of at least one object, and return it back to the other one. If you do so, the object that has accelerated will show a smaller time than the object whose velocity was constant (or zero).

Answer (score 1):

*Where is the flaw in my thinking?*

In your concept of time. It's little more than a cumulative measure of local motion, see [A World without Time: The Forgotten Legacy of Godel and Einstein]](http://www.amazon.co.uk/World-without-Time-Forgotten-Einstein/dp/0465092942). Your macroscopic motion relative to some other guy results in you measuring *his* local motion to be slow, whilst he measures *your* local motion to be slow. This sounds like something paradoxical, but it isn't. It's no more paradoxical than you saying he looks smaller than you whilst he says you looks smaller than him. Think of it like this: if you're separated by distance, distances look smaller, if you're separated by motion, motion looks slower.